# Navigate to the folder in which a file resides linux

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm trying to navigate to the directory in which a file resides. i.e. I'm trying to

```
cd $(which chromedriver)
```

That errors for obvious reasons `cd: not a directory: /usr/local/bin/chromedriver`

Is there either

1. An alternative to `cd` that navigates to the directory of a file, or
2. A way to handle or parse the output of `which` so that it's generalisable (i.e. not just removing the last 10 characters in the case of `chromedriver`, but which works for all applications)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `dirname` to strip path

```
cd "$(dirname "$(which chromedriver)")"
```

using `xargs`

```
cd "$(which chromedriver | xargs dirname)"
```

Comment: Or `cd $(dirname $(which chromedriver))`

Comment: [Quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). `cd "$(dirname "$FILEPATH")"`